# Windows commandline utility to get PCI Bus connected devices information?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, pci

I  want a command for the Windows commandline which  shows all PCI  BUS connected Devices information like , LSPCI  command does in LINUX . Can I use WMIC TOOL in XP to get that info . 
  If so  please help me in giving a step by  step  procedure in getting that information .

Comment: DOS tools will not work in XP, you need some native windows command line tools. There is no DOS in Windows NT series.

Comment: old question bumped up by community ;p. We quite commonly have people confusing cmd/windows command shell with 'dos'. I'm rather surprised this one didn't get caught.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a command-line method to enumerate PCI devices included with Windows XP.  However, you can [download the DevCon utility from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272/EN-US) and use it to accomplish this.

The above link lists all the command line options for it, including this one that will list all present PCI devices:

```
devcon find pci\*
```

Save the contents of the package in a directory from where you run the script. For example, if you save the contents in Downloads, cd to the directory in Command Prompt and then type the line.